# Как красиво распечатать org.json.JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, gson, печать

У меня есть такой JSONObject, который с помощью sout распечатывается так:

```
{"key1":"value1","key_j":{"key":"value"}}
```

Чтобы распечать его в стобик использую следущий подход:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonElement je = JsonParser.parseString(jsonObject.toString());
        String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

и при распечатке prettyJsonString получаю следующий результат:

```
{
  "members": {
    "key1": {
      "value": "value1"
    },
    "key_j": {
      "members": {
        "key": {
          "value": "value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как избавиться от этих `members` и `Co` или по-другому красиво распечатать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть `org.json.JSONObject`, то его не нужно парсить с помощью gson, для того, чтобы красиво распечатать.

В библиотеке json-lib есть соответствующий метод [`JSONObject::toString(int)`](https://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#toString(int)), который красиво печатает, только ему нужно указать параметр для создания отступов.

> Создает красивый печатный текст JSON для этого JSONObject.
>
> Внимание: этот метод предполагает, что структура данных ациклична.
>
> Указано:
> toString в интерфейсе JSON
> Параметры:
> indentFactor — количество пробелов, добавляемых к каждому уровню отступа.

Теперь `JSONObject` можно вывести с помощью sout.

```
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(4));
```